# Why Airflow didn't start the new Dag on the next scheduled time?

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

For example, I created a new DAG on 11:30. The DAG supposed to run on the first minute of every hour (Cron: 0 * * * *).
I expected the DAG start on 12:00. However the DAG and first started on 13:00.

What is going on here?

I checked the backend Mysql `dag` table, the `next_dagrun` column of the new dags shows 12:00.

Answer (score 1):

Quote from the Airflow [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/scheduler.html):

> If you run a DAG on a schedule_interval of one day, the run with execution_date 2019-11-21 triggers soon after 2019-11-21T23:59.

> Let’s Repeat That, the scheduler runs your job one schedule_interval AFTER the start date, at the END of the period.

Think about it as if it's the actual start date refers to the previous execution date, dag runs will happen after the interval is passed. So when you see `next_dagrun` at 12:00, that will get executed (`Start Date` column on *DAG Runs* UI) at 13:00 and so on.

In other words, if you created the DAG at 11:30, at 12:00 your first `schedule_interval` wasn't completed yet. For me the trick to finally understand what was going on, was to play around with the `start_date` param.

Hope that works for you!