# AirFlow not running schedule

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a very simple dag which is supposed to run every Monday at 19:10. The dag is as follows:

```
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator


args = {'owner': 'AirFlow'}

with DAG(dag_id='schedule_test_weekly', default_args=args, schedule_interval="20 21 * * 1", tags=['Scheduler test'],
         start_date=days_ago(2), catchup=False) as dag:
    test_scheduler_health = BashOperator(task_id="test_test_weekly", bash_command="echo Hello World", dag=dag)
```

But, it does not trigger. If I change the `schedule_interval` to `schedule_interval="*/5 * * * *"` it will run every 5 minutes without a problem. But I can't have it run every Monday at the said time. I checked many guides and posts online. Most mention the executer should be `LocalExecutor` and database connection should be set to postgres. I have these configs:

```
sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:pass2@localhost:5432/airflow
sql_alchemy_pool_enabled = True
sql_alchemy_pool_size = 10
executor = LocalExecutor
```

I also used cronhub to check my cron schedule. I think it is correct. Am I missing anything or doing something wrong?

Comment: Try checking this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66566864/10569220). There is no problem with the executor or the database, is just how scheduling works on Airflow. By the way, I think cron for every monday at 19:10 is: " 10 19 * * 1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is not using `start_date` correctly.

If you want a weekly job to run today (Monday), the start_date needs to be last week (Monday). The reason explained in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65196624/14624409).

So (assuming today is 05-Apr-2021) your DAG needs to be:

```
with DAG(dag_id='schedule_test_weekly',
         default_args=args,
         schedule_interval="10 19 * * 1",
         tags=['Scheduler test'],
         start_date=datetime(2021, 3, 29), # Monday 
         catchup=False
         ) as dag:
```

The first run will start on `2021-04-05` (today) with `execution_date` of `2021-03-29`.

The next run will start on `2021-04-12` with `execution_date` of `2021-04-05` and following on with that pattern as weekly job.

Comment: I tried. Still not working. I went as far as a month ago. I discovered that if I pass one day in the schedule_interval it wont work. Could there be a bug in AirFlow?

Comment: Try changing the dag_id

Comment: Wow! That seems to have fixed it! Thanks! But do you know what the problem with the previous dag_id is?

Comment: Also, can you add that to the response so I can choose it as the correct response?

Comment: It shouldnt happen but sometimes in older versions you must change the dag_id when you change the interval, its a side effect of the scheduling mechanism that is based on interval since the last run (your last run wasnt on Monday so it confuses the scheduler) so new dag_id gives a fresh start. I dont add it to the answer because this shouldnt happen in updated Airflow versions.