# Why is airflow not running the most recent task

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I've set up a dag with the following parameters

```
local_tz = pendulum.timezone('US/Eastern')  

default_args = {
    'retries': 3,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='some_dag',
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 8, tzinfo=local_tz),
    schedule_interval='0 16 8 * *',
    default_args=default_args,
    catchup=True
)
```

I am expecting the most recent task run to be on May 8th, however, I only see February 8th, March 8th, and April 8th.  I can't seem to figure out why Airflow stops in April.

[image]

It is currently May 25th so shouldn't the May 8th dag run have backfilled along with the other months? To be clear, I have just deployed this dag today, so all of the executed dag runs including the missing May 8th are backfills.

Comment: May will run in June

Comment: I don't understand why... according to the docs the first execution is start_date + schedule_interval, and then at every interval.  May 8th has already passed, shouldn't it have run in May?

Comment: As said before, this is the expected behavior since the interval is not done yet, the run for May, will be run in June. Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66566864/10569220) as an example. My suggestion is to play around with `start_date` and compare the information shown at Dag Runs menu in the UI.

Comment: took me a bit but yes it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected.
As you mentioned Airflow schedule tasks at the end of interval.
According to your setup the scheduling will look like:

The `1st` run will start on `2021-02-08` this run `execution_date` will be `2021-01-08`

The `2nd` run will start on `2021-03-08` this run `execution_date` will be `2021-02-08`

The `3th` run will start on `2021-04-08` this run `execution_date` will be `2021-03-08`

The `4th` run will start on `2021-05-08` this run `execution_date` will be `2021-04-08`

The `5th` run will start on `2021-06-08` this run `execution_date` will be `2021-05-08`

Since you actually set the DAG to start on `2021-05-26` Airflow executed at that moment `1st-4th` runs because the interval has ended for these runs. The `5th` run did not start yet because the interval has not endded yet it will end on `2021-06-08`.

You can read more extensive explanation about why Airflow behaves like that in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66288641/14624409).